# XPath: Select any div that contains one or more descendant divs with a specific class

Tags: xpath

Assume that following HTML snippet exists somewhere in the `<body>` element of a web page:

```
<div id="root_1000" class="root bacon">
    <ul>
        <li id="item_1234567" class="active">
            <div class="userpost author_4281">
                <div>This text should be visible.<div>
            </div>
            <ul><li>Some item</li></ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="root_2000" class="root bacon">
    <ul>
        <li id="item_8675309" class="active">
            <div class="userpost author_3333">
                <div>
                  This text, and as the DIV.root that contains it, should be hidden.
                <div>
            </div>
            <ul><li>Another item</li></ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="root_3000" class="root bacon">
    <ul>
        <li id="item_7654321" class="active">
            <div class="userpost author_9877">
                <div>This text should be visible.<div>
            </div>
            <ul><li>Yet another item</li></ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

So here's my question: what would the XPath syntax be to select the `div.root` that contains info posted by author #3333 (i.e. `div[class~="author_3333"]`)?

The following XPath statement will properly match the `div.userpost` element associated with author #3333 that I want to hide, but does not include the `<ul><li>Another item</li></ul>` node, which I also need to hide:

```
.//div[contains(@class, 'author_3333')]
```

What I want to do is select the closest `div.root` ancestor associated with the node that my XPath statement matches.  Any help would be greatly appreciated... thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this XPath expression:

```
.//div[contains(@class, 'author_3333')]/ancestor::div[contains(@class,'root')][1]
```

**Output is:**

```
<div id="root_2000" class="root bacon">
    <ul>
        <li id="item_8675309" class="active">
            <div class="userpost author_3333">
                <div>
                    This text, and as the DIV.root that contains it, should be hidden.
                </div>
            </div>
            <ul>
                <li>Another item</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect -- this works like a charm!  Now to understand it... what does the `[1]` at the end do?

Comment: I implemented it nearly literally: "the closest div.root ancestor". The closest means the first, hence the `[1]` for the first _div ancestor_.

Answer (score 2):

you need to get the parent node that has the second `div` as its child, something like:

```
//div[.//div[contains(@class, "author_3333")]]
```